# Why there is no error when I give same name to two list elements in R

Tags: r, data-structures

I got this question while doing some practicals using R. So here is the scenario,

```
v = list(bob=c(2,3,5),bob=c("aa","bb"))
```

I have a list named `v` and there are two list elements both named as `bob`. When I compile this it does not give any error. But the most interesting factor is if I try to print `bob` using `list name` it gives me this result,

```
> v$bob
[1] 2 3 5
```

But if I print `bob` using `attach()` command it returns another way around.

```
> attach(v)
> bob
[1] "aa" "bb"
> detach(v)
```

These two different results made me curious and please can someone help to understand the underline theory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `attach`, it is overriding the first 'bob' i.e. 2, 3, 5 with the last entry.  If we want to reverse it, use `rev` which just reverse the order of list elements and thus the first element of list will now be the last one

```
attach(rev(v))
```

-check

```
> bob
[1] 2 3 5
```

In general, it is recommended **not** to use `attach`.

If we want to create an object for a specific element use `assign`

```
assign(names(v)[1], v[[1]])
```

---

Regarding the question `why there is no error` in duplicate names of a `list`, it is a feature of `list` to have duplicate names as do `matrix` can have duplicate names.  But, in `data.frame`, it is not allowed as there are functions in place to check for duplicates i.e. `make.unique` thus guaranteeing unique names

```
make.unique(c('bob', 'bob'))
[1] "bob"   "bob.1"
```

i.e. if we convert the `list` to a data.frame (after correcting for `length` i.e make the `length` same for the `list` elements - a `data.frame` is a `list` with equal length of its elements in addition to some more attributes)

```
data.frame(lapply(v, `length<-`, max(lengths(v))))
  bob bob.1
1   2    aa
2   3    bb
3   5  <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please can you correct me if I'm wrong? So here in the first scenario what happens is we are saving only the first list element am I right.

Comment: @JanakaEkanayake when you attach it goes through the names of the `list` and attach and as `bob` is repeated, and the creation of the objects happens from the top element, the value stored is getting replaced when it reach the last duplicate

Comment: @JanakaEkanayake Yes, object names should be unique i.e. `x <- 1` you create an object and later you do `x <- 'a'`, the 'x' will be a character object i.e. there is. no type constraint as in other languages

Comment: @akun thanks for the clear and precise explanation